# Retrive selected value of ng-select - Angular8

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am a novice with Angular 8.
 
I created the following dropdown menu, in a component, that works very well for me:

```
<ng-select class="w-25 p-3" placeholder="{{'author' | translate}}" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
        <ng-option>{{'author' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'title' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'date' | translate}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Now I would like to know how I can retrive the selected element in the `ts` file of the same component.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `[(ngModel)]` attribute to the attributes of the `ng-select`, and pass its value to the triggering.

```
<ng-select (change)="changeFn(selection)" [(ngModel)]="selection" class="w-25 p-3" placeholder="{{'author' | translate}}" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
        <ng-option>{{'author' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'title' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'date' | translate}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Then in the ts file:

```
export class myComponent {

    public val: string;

    changeFn(val) {
        console.log("Dropdown selection:", val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Memo, instead of declaring the val variable you should declare the selection in the ts file

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `change` event to capture the selected value.

```
<!-- Template -->
<ng-select (change)="changeFn" class="w-25 p-3" placeholder="{{'author' | translate}}" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
        <ng-option>{{'author' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'title' | translate}}</ng-option>
        <ng-option>{{'date' | translate}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>

<!-- Component ts file -->

changeFn(val) {
     console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: it should work. could you create `stackblitz` or `sandbox` example?

Comment: The problem is that it won't even trigger the method. Now I make attempts, in case of failure I will make a sandbox...

Comment: Resolved. I added the missing pieces. In practice I added `[(ngModel)]` which must be the parameter to pass to the triggering function, that is the selection of the drop-down menu. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

you can add >> [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" to get value

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 text-left">
  <ng-select 
    [items]="countries.countries" 
    bindLabel="country" 
    bindValue="country_code" 
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="getCountry()">
   </ng-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! in typescript just put selectedCountry with same data type as countries.countries.

Answer (score 3):

First in .ts file i created object:

```
cities4 = [];

selectedCityIds: string[];
```

Second, install `npm i @ng-select/ng-select` :

Next add:

```
<ng-select [items]="cities4"
           [virtualScroll]="true"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="id"
           placeholder="Select city"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCityId">
</ng-select>
```